# How to remove a horizontal scrollbar appearing while using twitter bootstrap on mobile menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

please help me out here. 
I styled a twitter bootstrap menu, but a horizontal scroll bar is appearing, when I am on the mobile version:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCKZO.jpg

I was able to reproduce it on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mXLSk/

I am using this to style the mobile version, but there has to be somewhere hidden another style that is letting the scrollbar appear.

```
 @media (max-width: 767px) { 
    #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
        background-color: #fff;

        a {
            padding: 7px 40px;
        }
    }
 }
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

.navbar-nav is using negative margins which is causing the content to flow outside of the container. Which is the ultimate reason of the scroll bar. Changing that to a positive padding should fix it =)

```
.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7.5px 15px;
}
```

[JSfiddle to the padding / margin change.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/mXLSk/3/)

Comment: ...but why?  If your answer is "override it", why was it there in the first place?  I would assume there's some reason behind it...

Comment: I realise this is an old answer, but I'd like to know why it was there in the first place aswell.

Comment: @Maritim Hey, regarding why the scroll bar was visible. There was multiple nested containers. The children containers were flowing outside of the parent container ( maybe there was too much text or something ), there was overflow: scroll on the parent container so a scroll bar was visible.